# how can import template.html in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack

i want to include template in my typescript how can do that??

```
var template = import './template.html'
```

i use web pack and bundle all file into one javascript file.

i use angularjs (v1) and want to build component base project using typescript gulp and webpack and now i use this code.

```
declare var require:any;
import  './cart.template.html';
import {cartController} from './cart.controller'

export var cartComponent = {
    template: require('./cart.template.html'),
    controller:cartController
}
```

is there any better solution for doing this???

Answer (score 0):

first, declare an HTML module like this:

```
declare module "*.html" {
const content: string;
export default content;
}
```

then, use it:

```
import * as template from "template.html";

 @Component({
 selector: 'home',
 directives: [RouterLink],
 template: template
 })
```

Comment: For some reason it complains that it can't find module template.html. But require works perfectly. Do you know how to do it with typescript?